How to reference dll's from Artifact Feed on release build
The scenario 
I have a project where I broke them down into components e.g. UI, API and Libraries are build as separate project adding project reference as needed.  
This works fine as I go about with my dev work on my localhost or local machine. The project is built into a single solution file.
The current state 
I create a CI/CD process, wherein the solution gets built and compiled into our dev/test or prod servers. This works file as the libraries are bundled into the build process as a project reference.
The ideal state 
What I was hoping to achieve would be this:  
1- When the CI triggers, the solution gets built but I was intending for the libraries to get built and packed.
2- On the CD part, the libraries gets pushed into the Artifact feed... and main project gets release into the respective server. But, the release process would update or pull (for lack of better word) the libraries from the Artifact feed instead of its (library) being a project reference.
What's the best way to achieve this?
Thanks.


Publish the libraries as Nuget packages to the Azure Artifacts 2) then reference the packages from the application(s) that use them. See Get started with NuGet packages in Azure Artifacts and Publish NuGet packages with Azure Pipelines


From your description, you need to publish the Libraries project to Artifacts Feed and then use it in the CD Part to build main project.
I suggest you adjust your CI/CD Pipeline structure.
You can use the CI Pipeline to Pack and Push the libraries project to Artifacts feed. And we can use CD Pipeline to reference the package and build the main project.
If you do a Push operation in a CD Pipeline, it will push artifacts repeatedly every time the CD Pipeline runs. It will lead to pushing duplicate artifacts package content or version conflicts.
You can use the Nuget package to save the dll files and push to Azure Artifacts.
Here is an example: Dotnet core
CI Pipeline:
  steps:
  - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
    inputs:
      nuGetServiceConnections: <NAME_OF_YOUR_SERVICE_CONNECTION>

  - script: |
      dotnet build <CSPROJ_PATH> --configuration <CONFIGURATION>
      dotnet pack <CSPROJ_PATH> -p:PackageVersion=<YOUR_PACKAGE_VERSION> --output <OUTPUT_DIRECTORY> --configuration <CONFIGURATION>
      dotnet nuget push <PACKAGE_PATH> --source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/nuget/v3/index.json --api-key <ANY_STRING>
    displayName: "Build, pack and push

To use the package in the Artifacts Feed, you can add the package reference in your main project(.csproj file).
For example:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="custompackagename" Version="xxx" />
</ItemGroup>

Then you can add the artifacts feed as resource in the nuget.config file.
For example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="test1" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xx/xx/_packaging/xx/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

</configuration>

When you build your main project in CD Pipeline, you can use dotnet resotore/nuget restore to download the dlls in the nuget package.
